# Assign/map colors to the points in Seaborn.regplot (Python 3)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a `seaborn` plot that I want to annotate with colors (preferably with a legend as well witht he color mapping).  I see that the `regplot` has a `color` method.  I don't know how to take use of this.

I set up my I tried a few different ways by either giving the `color` method a dictionary that maps the `{index : color}` and even added the color values to the dataframe itself.

**How can I map the points with the colors I assigned?**

```
np.random.seed(0)

# Create dataframe
DF_0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,2)), columns=["x","y"])

# Label to colors
D_idx_color = {**dict(zip(range(0,25), ["#91FF61"]*25)),
               **dict(zip(range(25,50), ["#BA61FF"]*25)),
               **dict(zip(range(50,75), ["#91FF61"]*25)),
               **dict(zip(range(75,100), ["#BA61FF"]*25))}
DF_0["color"] = pd.Series(list(D_idx_color.values()), index=list(D_idx_color.keys()))

# Plot
sns.regplot(data=DF_0, x="x", y="y") #works, plot below

# sns.regplot(data=DF_0, x="x", y="y", color="color") # doesn't work
# ValueError: to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "color"
# could not convert string to float: 'color'

# sns.regplot(data=DF_0, x="x", y="y", color=DF_0["color"]) # doesn't work
# ValueError: to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "('#91FF61', '#91FF61', ...

# sns.regplot(data=DF_0, x="x", y="y", color=D_idx_color) # doesn't work
# ValueError: to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "(0, 1, 2, ...
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to overplot some of those points in different colors, and then have a legend for the colors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `scatter_kws`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(0)

# Create dataframe
DF_0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,2)), columns=["x","y"])
DF_0['color'] =  ["#91FF61"]*25 + ["#BA61FF"]*25 + ["#91FF61"]*25 + ["#BA61FF"]*25
#print DF_0

sns.regplot(data=DF_0, x="x", y="y", scatter_kws={'c':DF_0['color']})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Seaborn throws an error `Supply a 'c' argument or a 'color' kwarg but not both; they differ but their functionalities overlap.`

Comment: Nowadays you need to use the `color` keyword and provide a list of colors: `sns.regplot(data=DF_0, x="x", y="y", scatter_kws={'color': list(DF_0['color'].values)})`.

Comment: @MERose's solution didn't work for me, but the original answer worked when I also added `color: None`.

Comment: In my case, adding `"color": None` to the `scatter_kws`, as suggested by @Joakim was almost the solution. The remaining issue was that there were some `None` values in my color column.